# Let $x_k = \frac{3k+4}{k-5}$. Given $\epsilon \gt 0$, find an integer $K$ such that $\vert{x_k - 3}\vert\lt \epsilon$, $\forall k\gt K$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So, the question is asking me to find an integer $K$ such that $x_k\rightarrow 3$. I don't really understand what it means when it says "find a $K$". How would I go about this?

Comment: Two answers have already been give. I'd like to add that their answers can be adapted  for a more general case: Let $x_k= f(k)/g(k)$ where $f, g$ are polynomials in $k$ of the same degree. (in your case both are linear). Then $x_k\to L$ as $k\to \infty$ where $L$ is the ratio of the leading coefficients of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Note that:
$$
\left|\frac{3k+4}{k-5} - 3\right| = \left|\frac{19}{k-5}\right| = \frac{19}{|k-5|}
$$
Therefore if $K = 5+ \dfrac{19}{\epsilon}$, then $k > K \implies \dfrac{19}{|k-5|} < \dfrac{19}{K-5} = \epsilon$,

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You have
$$x_k = \frac{3k+4}{k-5} = \frac{3(k-5)+19}{k-5} = 3 +\frac{19}{k-5}$$

Now can you find $K_\epsilon$ such that for $k > K_\epsilon$ you have
$$\frac{19}{k-5} < \epsilon$$